# Solve $\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{4}{x-2}+\frac{4}{x-3}-\frac{1}{x-4}<\frac{1}{30} \forall x\in R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I [plugged this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=1%2F(x-1)-4%2F(x-2)%2B4%2F(x-3)-1%2F(x-4)%3C1%2F30) into WolframAlpha. It gave the factorized form as:

$$\frac{(x-7)(x-6)(x+1)(x+2)}{(x-4)(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)}>0$$

Once we've reached this point, I know how to find the solution for $x$. But, currently, I am having trouble converting the given question expression into the factorized form above. I started off strong with:

$$(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-4})+(\frac{4}{x-3}-\frac{4}{x-2})<\frac{1}{30}$$
which simplifies to:
$$\frac{-3}{(x-1)(x-4)}+\frac{12}{(x-3)(x-2)}<\frac{1}{30}$$
which simplifies to:
$$\frac{3x^2-15x+10}{(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)}<\frac{1}{90}$$

and now this is a dead end! As you can see, I got to the denomiator, but the numerator is not what I expected it to be. I could transfer $1/30$ to the LHS but that would bring the deadly fourth power into the numerator. If this was a competitive exam question, I would not be sitting in the hall factorizing fourth powers...

> Is there a simpler method to factorize the LHS? Or is there an altogether different approach to solve this question?

Comment: Sorry........ you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the inequality, *leonbloy* already gave you the best suggestion.
To reconstruct WolframAlpha answer, doesn't seem that there be a shorter way other
than the plain

$$
\eqalign{
  & {{x^{\,2}  - 5x - 2} \over {\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right)\left( {x - 3} \right)\left( {x - 4} \right)}} - {1 \over {30}} =   \cr 
  &  = {{30x^{\,2}  - 150x - 60 - \left( {x^{\,4}  - 10x^{\,3}  + 35x^{\,2}  - 50x + 24} \right)} \over {30\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right)\left( {x - 3} \right)\left( {x - 4} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  =  - {{x^{\,4}  - 10x^{\,3}  + 5x^{\,2}  + 100x + 84} \over {30\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right)\left( {x - 3} \right)\left( {x - 4} \right)}} =   \cr 
  &  =  - {{\left( {x + 1} \right)\left( {x + 2} \right)\left( {x - 6} \right)\left( {x - 7} \right)} \over {30\left( {x - 1} \right)\left( {x - 2} \right)\left( {x - 3} \right)\left( {x - 4} \right)}} \cr} 
$$
where the factorization in the last passage is to be obtained by Ruffini's rule.

Comment: I understand that the last factorization requires slight trial and error. After we find out that x=-1 is a root, the remaining cubic is easy to solve. BTW: I learnt Ruffini's rule as [synthetic division](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/synthdiv.htm), both seem to be synonymous.

Comment: @GaurangTandon: well, apart from naming, everything comes down to the fact that , for a monic polynomial, the zeros shall divide the last factor and $(x-x_0)$ shall divide the whole polynomial.

Comment: I understand this.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at those denominators, there seems to be some symmetry around $x=5/2$. Replacing $u=x-5/2$ we get

$$\frac{1}{u+\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{4}{u+\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{4}{u-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{u-\frac{3}{2}}$$

Now, $\frac{1}{u+B/2}-\frac{1}{u-B/2}=-\frac{4B}{4u^2-B^2}$ so the above reduces to

$$ -\frac{12}{4u^2-9}+\frac{16}{4u^2-1}$$

Letting know $s=4u^2 $ we have

$$-\frac{12}{s-9}+\frac{16}{s-1} < \frac{1}{30}$$ which produces a quadratic inequation, which you should be able to solve - with the additional restriction $s\ge 0$. From that, you recover $x =  5/2 + u = (5\pm  \sqrt{s})/2 $

Comment: That's nice! :D